# Discord.py get requests left

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

As far as I know the rate limit from discord is 10,000 requests per 10 minutes. I want to know how many requests I have left so I can e.g. slow down the bot so it doesn't get banned from discord.
I only found is_ws_ratelimited but this only gives me a bool and this is not what I want

Comment: "...so it doesn't get banned"? Excuse my ignorance but I highly doubt they'd ban the bot for reaching the limit, they'd just return a 429 error until the 10 minutes have passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Discord Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits), every request returns optional HTTP headers containing the calls you have remaining. You are probably most likely interested in the header `X-RateLimit-Remaining` which contains how many requests you have left.

`X-RateLimit-Reset` gives you a unix timestamp for the date when the limit resets.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py lets you use a http request logger using aiohttp library using the http_trace parameter for Client. This should return the values to you in your console for you to see for information. You can simply put:

```
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import TraceConfig, TraceRequestEndParams
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger('discord.http')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)


async def on_request_end(session, context, params: TraceRequestEndParams):
    rate_limit_headers = ['X-RateLimit-Limit', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 'X-RateLimit-Reset', 'X-RateLimit-Reset-After', 'X-RateLimit-Bucket']
    headers = params.response.headers
    rate_limit_info = {header: headers.get(header) for header in rate_limit_headers if header in headers}
    if rate_limit_info:
        logger.info(f"Rate Limit Info: {rate_limit_info}")

trace_config = TraceConfig()
trace_config.on_request_end.append(on_request_end)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all(), http_trace=trace_config)
```